# Failed when put cache to file in laravel

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5

When i run

```
Cache::put('max_age','100',60));
```

Then the error said that

```
file_put_contents(storage/framework/cache/data/8f/87/8f87426f74633c0fa8f717150f13e8fc0404d63c): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Please help me to fix this bug! Thanks!

Comment: make sure you have write permission for `storage` directory for your laravel app

Comment: i think it would be "permission denied" error instead of "no such file or directory" error if i didn't have write permission? Alright? But i will try. Thank you :)